# wxMaxima: understanding ratcoef

Tags: wxmaxima

Ran into the following behaviour from `ratcoef` that I don't understand, and was hoping someone could help clarify what's happening.

```
ratcoef(3*sqrt(x)+5/sqrt(x),x,1/2);
    > 3
```

as epected. However,

```
ratcoef(x^(3/2)+3*sqrt(x)+5/sqrt(x),x,1/2);
    > 0
```

and yet changing the first power from `3/2` to `3` gives:

```
ratcoef(x^(3)+3*sqrt(x)+5/sqrt(x),x,1/2);
    > 3
```

The documentation clearly says to not use `ratcoef` for negative coefficients, but I can't see how the limitation would explain these results. Any suggestions would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. Not sure what's going on there. Maybe you can take it up on the Maxima mailing list, or file a bug report. Sorry I can't be more helpful!